# Parsing the Httpurlconnection get response

Tags: android, parsing, get, httpurlconnection

I have a method calling an api using Httpurlconnection get method,

Please find the method i have written:

```
       private String sendGet(CallWebserviceActivity context) throws Exception {
       String url = "http://myurl/";
       URL obj = new URL(url);
       HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)                               obj.openConnection();
       con.setRequestMethod("GET");
       con.setDoOutput(true);
       int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
       System.out.println("\nSending 'Get' request to URL : " +    url+"--"+responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

       System.out.println("Response : -- " + response.toString());
       return response.toString();
    }
```

Here i am getting a string of the format JSON Object as a result.I want to able to take result as value of the key so that i can show that in my android activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a JSONObject from string. Then get the value from key ...

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
String value = jsonResponse.getString("Key");
```

Note that string should be properly formatted JSON.